# Django Celery cannot query postgres db inside task

Tags: python, django, postgresql, redis, celery

In my celery task I try to query my postgres db. But I always get following error:
[image]

```
task.py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def ImportFiles(self, activity_file_list, user_id_list,activityfile_id,file_type_list):
    print('Task ImportFiles started')
    myuser = User.objects.get(pk=user_id_list[0])
    print("USER:")
    print(myuser)
```

---

```
settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
...
    'celery',
...
]
...
DATABASES = {
'default': {
     'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
     'NAME': 'geodjango',
     'USER': 'postgres',
     'PASSWORD': 'postgres',
},
}

...

CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379'
```

---

```
celery.py
# Default settings from celery tutorial:
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery
from django.conf import settings
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'geodjango.settings')
app = Celery('geodjango', broker='redis://localhost')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')
app.autodiscover_tasks(lambda: settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
```

---

**Following easy scenario works:**

If I change my task.py and execute just a simple for loop.

```
task.py
@shared_task(bind=True)
def ImportFiles(self, activity_file_list, user_id_list,activityfile_id,file_type_list):
    print('Task ImportFiles started')
    progress_recorder = ProgressRecorder(self)
    result = 0
    seconds = 10
    for i in range(seconds):
        print("for: " + str(i))
        time.sleep(1)
        result += i
        progress_recorder.set_progress(i + 1, seconds, description="Downloading")
    print("FOR LOOP FINISHED")
    return 'Task Complete'
```

Celery output:
[image]

So it looks like celery is working, but somehow I cannot make querys to my postgres db. I'm devolping currently on a windows machine... Can someone please help me?

Edit: I start celery with following commandline:

```
celery -A geodjango.celery worker --loglevel=info --pool=eventlet
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60179472/databasewrapper-objects-created-in-a-thread-can-only-be-used-in-that-same-thread

See accepted answer, it says it's something to do with Windows OS, use L*Nux based os.

Comment: Thanks for the link, I think I also saw it yesterday. My problem is, that at the moment I don't have access to a linux machine. So I'm looking for a solution on Windows OS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution for windows:
I started my celery with following command:

```
celery -A geodjango.celery worker --loglevel=info --pool=eventlet
```

The problem seems the --pool=eventlet --> if I change pool to solo it works.
Following command works now and I can make my postgres queries.

```
celery -A geodjango.celery worker --loglevel=info --pool=solo
```

I'm not an expert, I think I saw --pool=eventlet in a tutorial so I used that. But with --pool=solo it works.

Here I found an article about the different pool options, maybe it also helps someone else: https://www.distributedpython.com/2018/10/26/celery-execution-pool/

Comment: what is geodjango?

Comment: @reza_khalafi it is a geographic web framework, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/contrib/gis/